# What is the operation of a number in between left double bar of norm symbol, $\vert x \vert y\vert\vert$?

Tags: optimization, definition, normed-spaces

I am reading the paper about [group lasso](http://faculty.washington.edu/nrsimon/standGL.pdf). The equation (3) in the paper has a number, $\sqrt p_{l}$, between left double bar of norm sign as: $\vert\sqrt p_{l}\vert\beta^{(l)}\vert\vert_{2}$ (where $\vert\vert \cdot \vert\vert$ is norm symbol). What is the operation here?

Excerpt from paper

> The $l1$ norm penalty promotes sparsity in the solution vector $β$.  Suppose,
>   further, that our predictor variables were divided into $m$ different groups. We
>   are given these group memberships and rather than sparsity in individual
>   elements of $β, we would like a solution which uses only a few of the groups.
>   Yuan and Lin [2007] proposed the Group Lasso criterion for this problem;
>   to find

$min_{\beta} \frac{1}{2} \vert\vert y-\sum_{l=1}^m X^{(l)}\beta^{(l)}\vert\vert^2_{2} + \vert\sqrt p_{l}\vert\beta^{(l)}\vert\vert_{2}  \tag{3}$

> where $X_{(l)}$ is the submatrix of X with columns corresponding to the predictors in group $l$, $β_{(l)}$ is the coefficient vector of that group, and $W_{l}$ is some penalty matrix, $p_{l}$ is the number of covariates in group {(l)}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely a typo for "$\sqrt{p_l} ||\beta^{(l)}||_2$".  Compare with equations 7, 8, and 10.

Note that equation 3 has "$p_\ell$" instead of "$p_l$" and the only other odd use of "$\ell$" in this paper is "$W_\ell$" two lines before equation 3.  This makes me think there could be a cut-and-paste splice here and not all minor variations in notation were caught.